# Is there a way to replace column names with column locations in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Power Query to append multiple queries together for financial data. I am trying to add in clean-up steps after the queries are appended, but the steps continue to use the column names rather than the location. The column numbers change on a monthly/yearly basis, and I would rather write M code now to automate the refreshes rather than have to go in every time the query is pulled with new columns and delete and re-add steps. Below is my code that is auto-generated when I replace null values with zeroes. Is there a way to change the names ("201501") with an index or location?

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Merged Columns",null,"0",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"201501", "201601", "201701", "201801", "201901", "201902", "201903", "201904", "201905", "201906", "201907", "201908", "201909", "201910", "201911", "201912", "202001", "202002", "202003", "202004", "202005", "202006", "202007", "202008", "202009", "202010", "202011", "202012", "Budget Ref"})

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

`= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Merged Columns",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Merged Columns"))`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table columns are `A`, `B`, `101`, `201`, `301`, `Z`, where only the numeric columns change names.

You can use the [Table.ColumnNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-columnnames) function to return them as a list

```
{ "A", "B", "101", "201", "301", "Z" }
```

and then filter this list to choose only the ones you want to do a replacement on.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(
      #"Merged Columns", null, "0", Replacer.ReplaceValue, 
      List.RemoveLastN(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Merged Columns"), 2), 1)
  )
```

I've chosen to remove the first two column names and the last column name. Adjust as appropriate for your use case.